# Rendering PyQGIS objects in MapCanvas

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

I'm quite new to PyQGIS and have what is probably a pretty basic question, but I haven't been able to pick it up from the documentation. I have a `QgsVectorLayer` object from a PostGIS server, and I want to render it in the Map Canvas. How do I go from vector layer object to rendered map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the other vector layers:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "your_database", "you", "password")
uri.setDataSource("public", "your_table", "the_geom")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "name_of_layer_in_the_canvas", "postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```